# Convert Tail-Call Recursive Code to Loop

Tags: python, recursion, interpreter

So, I'm in the midst of writing a programming language interpreter in Python, and one of the problems I'm concerned about is that since I've been using a lot of recursions to implement the interpreter, I'll get a stack overflow if the size of the code is too large. For example, I have a piece of code that evaluates an `and` operation. Since the language I'm implementing is a logic programming language (like Prolog), it needs to try out all the options, so it consumes a generator and loops over it looking at the rest of the `and` operation. Behold:

```
def evaluate_and(and_clauses, binds={}):
    if and_clauses == []:
        yield binds
    else:
        head, *tail = and_clauses
        possible = evaluate(head, binds)
        for p in possible:
            yield from evaluate_and(tail, p)
```

The issue with this is that if the `and` operation is buried deep within the program, and the call stack is already large, then if the `and` has too many clauses the interpreter will crash.

If anyone could suggest a way to make this not possible, that would be amazing!

PS: I have an even bigger problem, which is that since recursion is the only way to do looping in a logic programming language if you loop more than a 100 times in my language, it creates a stack overflow in my interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search for "python tail call optimization" results in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506625) which has a PyPI package, [`tco`](https://pypi.org/project/tco/). Converting your code to return lists rather than generators should be all you need.

> recursion is the only way to do looping in a logic programming language

This is wrong.

If you want it to stay as a generator, then you'll have to manually handle the stack. The following doesn't account for order so if you need that then you'll have to figure that out yourself.

```
def evaluate_and(and_clauses, binds={}):
    stack = [(clauses, binds)]
    while stack:
        and_clauses, binds = stack.pop()
        if and_clauses == []:
            yield binds
        else:
            head, *tail = and_clauses
            possible = evaluate(head, binds)
            for p in possible:
                stack.append((tail, p))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was actually in the middle of working on a fairly promising solution but was having problems with what seems to be weird pointer magic? I tried something similar to yours in function, and in the process realized that both your code, my new code, and my old code don't do what I want: it evaluates the entire `and` up to the last clause up front, instead of lazily doing it. Here's what I had: https://gist.github.com/christopherdumas/3877ba10f9e98e0d3f5d6b5dc896dfae.

Comment: Currently, I'm trying to get this to work: https://gist.github.com/christopherdumas/ef745b4c8166df738b83082896c4c30f. However, when the actual final `possibilities` generator is evaluated, it seems to have been set to the result of the final clause `eval`d with a blank possibilities? It's very strange. And if I try to keep track of the possibilities, in a stack, they all turn out to have the exact same contents, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Gort I'm not going to help you further. If you post a working question on Code Review I might.

Comment: Okay that's fine. I'm just grateful for any sort of help. Also I did more research and I was indeed wrong about looping (:. I'll continue to try to figure this out and post an answer here when I'm done.